# How do I get this footer to line up with the textarea? Flexbox doesn't seem to do it

Tags: css, flexbox, center, footer

I want the text at the bottom to be centered and line up with the text boxes. If I add a margin it will only work for my current screen size but when I drag the page to another sized monitor the spacing gets messed up.  How do I center the bottom part of this page with the textarea? Here is my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;


}


.contact-section {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 77vh;
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0,0,0,0.35), rgba(0,0,0,0.35)), url(img/colo.png);
    /* background-size: center; */
    background-position: center;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    padding: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.contact-section__text {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: x-large;
}

label {
    display: none;
} 

.contact input,
.contact textarea {
    margin: .5rem;
    font-weight: 1000;

} 
.contact textarea {
    margin-right: 1.25rem;
}
.contact-section__btn {
    padding: 12px 26px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: rgb(201, 83, 5);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
}
.contact-section__btn:hover,
.contact-section__btn:focus {
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(201, 83, 5);
    cursor: pointer;

}

input[type="text"], [type="email"], textarea {
    background-color: rgb(247, 204, 175);
    border-color: rgb(201, 83, 5);
    width: 400px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-right: 1.45rem;
}

.contact__txtarea label,
.textarea {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.email-form {
    margin-right: .80rem;
}
.addresses {
    /* background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99); */
    background-color:rgb(201, 83, 5);
    color: white;
    /* margin-top: 2rem; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
    /* padding-inline-start: 0; */
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.addresses__info1 {
    flex-direction: column;

}
.addresses__info2 {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.main_footer {

  /* background-color:rgb(99, 99, 99); */
  background-color:rgb(201, 83, 5);
    margin-top: 3.5rem;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.footer_links  { /*li*/
  margin: 0;
}

.footer_lists  { /*ul*/
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.footer_links a { /*li a*/
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.1rem;

}
.footer_links :hover {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
      <title>Contact | Feel free to email or call Us!</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact_nav_ft.css">
      <link href="img/colo.icon .png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav_list">
            <li ></li>
            <li class="nav_lists" style="float:right;"><a href="Colombia.html">Our Purpose</a></li>
            <li class="nav_lists"><a href="Colombian-cities.html">Cities</a></li>
            <li class="nav_lists"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="nav_lists"><a href="services.html">Our Services</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

  <main id="flex-container">
    <section class="contact-section">
      <div class="contact-section__text">
        <p>
            Shoot us an email or Give us a call!<br>
            We are always happy to answer any questions you may have!<br>
        </p>
      </div>
        <form action="" method="POST" class="contact">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                <input id="name" type="text"  placeholder="Your name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="email-form">
                <label for="email">Your Email</label>
                <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="contact__txtarea">
                <label for="text">Message</label>  
                <textarea  class="textarea" id="text" maxlength="500" placeholder="Your message here..." required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input class="contact-section__btn" type="submit" value="Send Message" required> 
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>


    <section class="addresses">
        <div class="addresses__info1">
            <p>Finds us on:</p>
            <img src="img/you.svg" alt="Youtube">
            <img src="img/insta.svg" alt="Instagram">
            <img src="img/face.svg" alt="Facebook">

            <p>Email us at: <a href="mailto:questions@countryofcol.com">questions@countryofcol.com</a><br>
            Call us at: <a href="tel:+57 118-647-0023">+57 118-647-0023</a><br></p>
        </div>


        <div class="addresses__info2">
            <p>Calle Maria 63 Oficina 702<br>
            Medellin 4665684<br>
            Colombia<br></p>

            <p>Tuesday-Saturday<br>
            9AM - 6PM COT<br></p>

        </div>

        <footer class="main_footer">
        <ul class="footer_lists">
            <li class="footer_links"><a href="terms.html">Terms</a></li>
            <li class="footer_links"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
        </footer> 

    </section>

<!--</section>-->
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
}

.contact-section {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 77vh;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)), url(img/colo.png);
  /* background-size: center; */
  background-position: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  padding: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.contact-section__text {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: x-large;
}

label {
  display: none;
}

.contact input,
.contact textarea {
  margin: .5rem;
  font-weight: 1000;
}

.contact textarea {
  margin-right: 1.25rem;
}

.contact-section__btn {
  padding: 12px 26px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: rgb(201, 83, 5);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
}

.contact-section__btn:hover,
.contact-section__btn:focus {
  background-color: white;
  color: rgb(201, 83, 5);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"],
[type="email"],
textarea {
  background-color: rgb(247, 204, 175);
  border-color: rgb(201, 83, 5);
  width: 400px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-right: 1.45rem;
}

.contact__txtarea label,
.textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.email-form {
  margin-right: .80rem;
}

.addresses {
  /* background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99); */
  background-color: rgb(201, 83, 5);
  color: white;
  /* margin-top: 2rem; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  /* padding-inline-start: 0; */
}

.addresses__info1 {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.addresses__info2 {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.main_footer {
  /* background-color:rgb(99, 99, 99); */
  background-color: rgb(201, 83, 5);
  margin-top: 3.5rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer_links {
  /*li*/
  margin: 0;
}

.footer_lists {
  /*ul*/
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.footer_links a {
  /*li a*/
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.footer_links :hover {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Contact | Feel free to email or call Us!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact_nav_ft.css">
  <link href="img/colo.icon .png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav_list">
      <li></li>
      <li class="nav_lists" style="float:right;"><a href="Colombia.html">Our Purpose</a></li>
      <li class="nav_lists"><a href="Colombian-cities.html">Cities</a></li>
      <li class="nav_lists"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav_lists"><a href="services.html">Our Services</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main id="flex-container">
    <section class="contact-section">
      <div class="contact-section__text">
        <p>
          Shoot us an email or Give us a call!<br> We are always happy to answer any questions you may have!<br>
        </p>
      </div>
      <form action="" method="POST" class="contact">
        <div>
          <label for="name">Your Name</label>
          <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="email-form">
          <label for="email">Your Email</label>
          <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="contact__txtarea">
          <label for="text">Message</label>
          <textarea class="textarea" id="text" maxlength="500" placeholder="Your message here..." required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input class="contact-section__btn" type="submit" value="Send Message" required>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>


    <section class="addresses">
      <div class="addresses__info1">
        <p>Finds us on:</p>
        <img src="img/you.svg" alt="Youtube">
        <img src="img/insta.svg" alt="Instagram">
        <img src="img/face.svg" alt="Facebook">

        <p>Email us at: <a href="mailto:questions@countryofcol.com">questions@countryofcol.com</a><br> Call us at: <a href="tel:+57 118-647-0023">+57 118-647-0023</a><br></p>
      </div>


      <div class="addresses__info2">
        <p>Calle Maria 63 Oficina 702<br> Medellin 4665684<br> Colombia
          <br></p>

        <p>Tuesday-Saturday<br> 9AM - 6PM COT<br></p>

      </div>

      <footer class="main_footer">
        <ul class="footer_lists">
          <li class="footer_links"><a href="terms.html">Terms</a></li>
          <li class="footer_links"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </footer>

    </section>

    <!--</section>-->
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That worked! What exactly did you do that changed it?

Comment: I defined the size of each section within the footer and also made it where it grows with the flex. check out the address-items for the changes

Answer (score 0):

So first you are doing a html structure error. You are trying to set `footer` into `main` but it should be out.

Body structure should be like:

```
<body>
   <header></header>
   <main></main>
   <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Then you are setting `height: 77vh;` in `contact-section` try to set `min-heigth: 77vh;` instead to make it more flexible.

If you want to remove the white strip over your footer, just remove the `margin-top` from your `footer`. But if all your orange section is a footer then you should set it all in footer instead of separated it in `section` and `footer`

### DEMO

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;


}


.contact-section {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 77vh;     /* Replaced from height to min-height */
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0,0,0,0.35), rgba(0,0,0,0.35)), url(img/colo.png);
    /* background-size: center; */
    background-position: center;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    padding: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.contact-section__text {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: x-large;
}

label {
    display: none;
} 

.contact input,
.contact textarea {
    margin: .5rem;
    font-weight: 1000;

} 
.contact textarea {
    margin-right: 1.25rem;
}
.contact-section__btn {
    padding: 12px 26px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: rgb(201, 83, 5);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
}
.contact-section__btn:hover,
.contact-section__btn:focus {
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(201, 83, 5);
    cursor: pointer;

}

input[type="text"], [type="email"], textarea {
    background-color: rgb(247, 204, 175);
    border-color: rgb(201, 83, 5);
    width: 400px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-right: 1.45rem;
}

.contact__txtarea label,
.textarea {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.email-form {
    margin-right: .80rem;
}
.addresses {
    /* background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99); */
    background-color:rgb(201, 83, 5);
    color: white;
    /* margin-top: 2rem; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
    /* padding-inline-start: 0; */
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.addresses__info1 {
    flex-direction: column;

}
.addresses__info2 {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.main_footer {

  /* background-color:rgb(99, 99, 99); */
  background-color:rgb(201, 83, 5);
    /*margin-top: 3.5rem;*/
    flex-direction: column;
}

.footer_links  { /*li*/
  margin: 0;
}

.footer_lists  { /*ul*/
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.footer_links a { /*li a*/
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.1rem;

}
.footer_links :hover {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
      <title>Contact | Feel free to email or call Us!</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact_nav_ft.css">
      <link href="img/colo.icon .png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav_list">
            <li ></li>
            <li class="nav_lists" style="float:right;"><a href="Colombia.html">Our Purpose</a></li>
            <li class="nav_lists"><a href="Colombian-cities.html">Cities</a></li>
            <li class="nav_lists"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="nav_lists"><a href="services.html">Our Services</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

  <main id="flex-container">
    <section class="contact-section">
      <div class="contact-section__text">
        <p>
            Shoot us an email or Give us a call!<br>
            We are always happy to answer any questions you may have!<br>
        </p>
      </div>
        <form action="" method="POST" class="contact">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                <input id="name" type="text"  placeholder="Your name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="email-form">
                <label for="email">Your Email</label>
                <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="contact__txtarea">
                <label for="text">Message</label>  
                <textarea  class="textarea" id="text" maxlength="500" placeholder="Your message here..." required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input class="contact-section__btn" type="submit" value="Send Message" required> 
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>


    <section class="addresses">
        <div class="addresses__info1">
            <p>Finds us on:</p>
            <img src="img/you.svg" alt="Youtube">
            <img src="img/insta.svg" alt="Instagram">
            <img src="img/face.svg" alt="Facebook">

            <p>Email us at: <a href="mailto:questions@countryofcol.com">questions@countryofcol.com</a><br>
            Call us at: <a href="tel:+57 118-647-0023">+57 118-647-0023</a><br></p>
        </div>


        <div class="addresses__info2">
            <p>Calle Maria 63 Oficina 702<br>
            Medellin 4665684<br>
            Colombia<br></p>

            <p>Tuesday-Saturday<br>
            9AM - 6PM COT<br></p>

        </div>

    </section>

<!--</section>-->
  </main>
  
  <footer class="main_footer">
    <ul class="footer_lists">
        <li class="footer_links"><a href="terms.html">Terms</a></li>
        <li class="footer_links"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer> 
</body>
</html>
```

### Demo with 1 footer

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;


}


.contact-section {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 77vh;     /* Replaced from height to min-height */
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0,0,0,0.35), rgba(0,0,0,0.35)), url(img/colo.png);
    /* background-size: center; */
    background-position: center;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    padding: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.contact-section__text {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: x-large;
}

label {
    display: none;
} 

.contact input,
.contact textarea {
    margin: .5rem;
    font-weight: 1000;

} 
.contact textarea {
    margin-right: 1.25rem;
}
.contact-section__btn {
    padding: 12px 26px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: rgb(201, 83, 5);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
}
.contact-section__btn:hover,
.contact-section__btn:focus {
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(201, 83, 5);
    cursor: pointer;

}

input[type="text"], [type="email"], textarea {
    background-color: rgb(247, 204, 175);
    border-color: rgb(201, 83, 5);
    width: 400px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-right: 1.45rem;
}

.contact__txtarea label,
.textarea {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.email-form {
    margin-right: .80rem;
}
.addresses {
    /* background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99); */
    background-color:rgb(201, 83, 5);
    color: white;
    /* margin-top: 2rem; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
    /* padding-inline-start: 0; */
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.addresses__info1 {
    flex-direction: column;

}
.addresses__info2 {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.main_footer {

  /* background-color:rgb(99, 99, 99); */
  background-color:rgb(201, 83, 5);
    /*margin-top: 3.5rem;*/
    flex-direction: column;
}

.footer_links  { /*li*/
  margin: 0;
}

.footer_lists  { /*ul*/
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.footer_links a { /*li a*/
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.1rem;

}
.footer_links :hover {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
      <title>Contact | Feel free to email or call Us!</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact_nav_ft.css">
      <link href="img/colo.icon .png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav_list">
            <li ></li>
            <li class="nav_lists" style="float:right;"><a href="Colombia.html">Our Purpose</a></li>
            <li class="nav_lists"><a href="Colombian-cities.html">Cities</a></li>
            <li class="nav_lists"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="nav_lists"><a href="services.html">Our Services</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

  <main id="flex-container">
    <section class="contact-section">
      <div class="contact-section__text">
        <p>
            Shoot us an email or Give us a call!<br>
            We are always happy to answer any questions you may have!<br>
        </p>
      </div>
        <form action="" method="POST" class="contact">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                <input id="name" type="text"  placeholder="Your name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="email-form">
                <label for="email">Your Email</label>
                <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="contact__txtarea">
                <label for="text">Message</label>  
                <textarea  class="textarea" id="text" maxlength="500" placeholder="Your message here..." required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input class="contact-section__btn" type="submit" value="Send Message" required> 
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>


    

<!--</section>-->
  </main>
  
  <footer class="main_footer">
  
    <div class="addresses">
        <div class="addresses__info1">
            <p>Finds us on:</p>
            <img src="img/you.svg" alt="Youtube">
            <img src="img/insta.svg" alt="Instagram">
            <img src="img/face.svg" alt="Facebook">

            <p>Email us at: <a href="mailto:questions@countryofcol.com">questions@countryofcol.com</a><br>
            Call us at: <a href="tel:+57 118-647-0023">+57 118-647-0023</a><br></p>
        </div>


        <div class="addresses__info2">
            <p>Calle Maria 63 Oficina 702<br>
            Medellin 4665684<br>
            Colombia<br></p>

            <p>Tuesday-Saturday<br>
            9AM - 6PM COT<br></p>

        </div>

    </div>
    <ul class="footer_lists">
        <li class="footer_links"><a href="terms.html">Terms</a></li>
        <li class="footer_links"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, I tried to recycle footer code from other pages without realizing that I was going to use more than that.  What does that min-height do?

Comment: The `min-height` is actualy fixing a minimum height of the container. But this container will stretch to contain all its content. So all others elements will be push down. Because maybe you did not see but in the answer you validate, in its demo, the form is going behind the section below (footer)... so on mobile that do not work at all...